# Can I export the Option Inspector settings?

Tags: options

I've customized my options via the option inspector but I doubt I'd remember all those obtuse settings. Is there a way to export or save them if my computer dies or I upgrade?

Comment: `Options[$FrontEnd]` or you can select display as text in the options inspector when showing the global preferences.

Comment: You can also just make a backup of your `$UserBaseDirectory` - that way, every setting/paclet/... will be backed up, not only front end preferences. (And since it's anyway a good idea to have frequent backups, you get the directory backed up for free in that case, no need to manually export anything)